# In Transact-SQL how do you change between Contains all and Contains any using a Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am building a report to act a simple search tool to search through a VARCHAR(MAX) text blob. I am trying to make it possible for the user to select two different search types: Contains All search terms, and Contains any. I am having trouble finding a syntax that works for changing between Contains all and Contains any. Below is the gist of how I want it to work. Thanks for the help!

```
Where Reprt.DateStamp >= @StartDate and Reprt.DateStamp <= @EndDate and
IF @SearchType = 'And'
        Reprt.ContentText like '%'+@SearchString1+'%' and
        Reprt.ContentText like '%'+@SearchString2+'%' and 
        Reprt.ContentText like '%'+@SearchString3+'%' and 
        Reprt.ContentText like '%'+@SearchString4+'%'
Else
        Reprt.ContentText like '%'+@SearchString1+'%' or
        Reprt.ContentText like '%'+@SearchString2+'%' or 
        Reprt.ContentText like '%'+@SearchString3+'%' or 
        Reprt.ContentText like '%'+@SearchString4+'%'
```

Comment: typo sorry Meant Trans or Transact-SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AND/OR` logic

```
Where Reprt.DateStamp >= @StartDate and Reprt.DateStamp <= @EndDate and
((@SearchType = 'And' and 
        Reprt.ContentText like '%'+@SearchString1+'%' and
        Reprt.ContentText like '%'+@SearchString2+'%' and 
        Reprt.ContentText like '%'+@SearchString3+'%' and 
        Reprt.ContentText like '%'+@SearchString4+'%')
or (@SearchType <> 'And'
        Reprt.ContentText like '%'+@SearchString1+'%' or
        Reprt.ContentText like '%'+@SearchString2+'%' or 
        Reprt.ContentText like '%'+@SearchString3+'%' or 
        Reprt.ContentText like '%'+@SearchString4+'%'))
```

Comment: for the or section I had to add `and (` after 'And', but other than that it works perfectly thanks you!